# Problem with Spring Cloud Stream configuration

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to upgrade the version of a legacy application. I'm trying to develop the part of amqp with spring-cloud-stream.
I can't listen in rabbitMQ queue, without exchange ( I can't change this way )
How can i implement a listener just for one queue??

This is my app-properties.yml

```
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: inputCollector
    stream:
      default:
        contentType: application/json
        declareExchange: false
      binders:
        rabbitmq:
          type: rabbit
      bindings:
        inputCollector-in-0:
          queueNameGroupOnly : true
          group : collector_result.Collections
          binder: rabbitmq
```

and my code

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AnyHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InputCollectorHandler.class);

    private final CollectorService collectorService;

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Event> inputCollector() {
        return user -> {
            LOG.info("event received", user);
            try {
                anyService.handleCollectorResponse(user);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Error processing message: " + user);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`declareExchange: false` must be under `...rabbit.defaults...` or `...rabbit.bindings.....consumer.`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties.